# Combine two service calls and return the values

Tags: javascript

hello I want to combine 2 calls. and return it. but if both fail I should catch it and if any of the 2 calls fail then that´s ok i can just return the one that worked.

this is what I tried.

I have the catch in both calls. how to move it to the promise.all?

```
router.get('/services', (req, res) => {

    let arr = [];

    const call1 = service1()
        .then(res => arr.push({ res, type: 'service1'} ))
        .catch(error => res.status(error.status).json(error));

    const call2 = service2()
        .then(res => arr.push({ res, type: 'service2'} ))
        .catch(error => res.status(error.status).json(error));
})

Promise.all([service1, service2]).then(values => { 
  // not sure what to do here
});
```

node version: v8.11.1

Comment: Which version of `Node` are you using?

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.catch` on the service call will ensure that the callback passed to `.then` in `Promise.all()` will always be called, so you need to handle the errors yourself:

```
async function callService(fn, type) {
  return service1().then(res => ({ res, type })).catch(err => ({ err }));
}

router.get('/services', (req, res) => {
  const calls = [callService(service1, 'service1'), callService(service2, 'service2')];
  return Promise.all(calls).then(arr => {
    if (arr.every(call => call.err)) {
      // Both elements in arr are errors, handle here
      return;
    }

    // At least 1 was not an error, handle here
  });
```

Comment: The return value of `.catch` is used instead of the return value from `.then` when your promise throws an error. This allows the promise to continue to be chained - otherwise, your `Promise.all` would have to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` will unfortunately return an error if a `Promise` fails, so it won't work the way you want it.

Assuming you're using `Node.js` **8 or above**, you can use `async/await` to make two asynchronous calls and check if one of them returns an error:

```js
router.get(`/services`, (req, res) => {
  // this is just a simple check, but gives you an idea
  const isError = (arg) => {
    return arg instanceof Error
  }

  async function processRequest() {
    const arr = []

    const call1 = await service1().catch(error => error)
    const call2 = await service2().catch(error => error)

    if (!isError(call1)) {
      arr.push({ res: call1, type: `service1` })
    }
    if (!isError(call2)) {
      arr.push({ res: call2, type: `service2` })
    }
    if (isError(cal1) && isError(cal2)) {
      res.status(call1.status).json(call1)
      return
    }
    res.status(200).json(arr)
  }
  processRequest()
})
```

---

Alternatively, if you're using `Node` **12.10 or above**, you could use `Promise.allSettled`, which will give you exactly what you need.

> Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either resolved or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

Applying it in your case, it would look like the following:

```js
router.get(`/services`, (req, res) => {
  Promise.allSettled([
    service1(),
    service2()
  ])
  .then(results => {
    const arr = results
      .filter(result => result.status === `fulfilled`)
      .map(result => result.value)

    if (arr.length === 0) {
      const { reason } = results.find(result => result.status === `rejected`)
      res.status(reason.status).json(reason)
      return
    }
    res.status(200).json(arr)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle other errors appropriately
    res.status(500).json(...)
  })
})
```

Comment: You mention `async`/`await` in your explanation but fail to use it when calling `service1` or `service2`. Should instead be something like: `const call1 = await service1().catch(error => error)`